Gradle Sync Error: Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'app (:app)' when applying custom gradle plugin for kotlin multiplatform project
I'm trying to implement a custom gradle plugin for my app module in a kotlin multiplatform project, but i keep ran into this error when i apply my custom plugin and sync project.
Error says to initialize target in app module but i already initiated.
The Stacktrace:
> Configure project :app
mmd is Coming
com.android.application
e: Please initialize at least one Kotlin target in 'app (:app)'.
Read more https://kotl.in/set-up-targets

w: The following Kotlin source sets were configured but not added to any Kotlin compilation:
 * commonMain
 * commonTest
You can add a source set to a target's compilation by connecting it with the compilation's default source set using 'dependsOn'.
See https://kotl.in/connecting-source-sets

w: Missing 'androidTarget()' Kotlin target in multiplatform project 'app (:app)'.
The Android Gradle plugin was applied without creating a corresponding 'android()' Kotlin Target:

plugins {
id("com.android.application")
kotlin("multiplatform")
}

kotlin {
androidTarget() // \<-- please register this Android target
}

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
  com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationExtension

> com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationExtension

* Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/dsl/ApplicationExtension
  at ApplicationGradlePlugin.apply(ApplicationGradlePlugin.kt:24)
  ...
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.build.api.dsl.ApplicationExtension
  at org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader$InstrumentingVisitableURLClassLoader.findClass(VisitableURLClassLoader.java:187)
  ... 215 more

CONFIGURE FAILED in 6s

My Custom Plugin in BuildSrc:
class ApplicationGradlePlugin : Plugin<Project> {
    override fun apply(target: Project) {
        with(target) {
            val libs = extensions.getByType<VersionCatalogsExtension>().named("libs")

            println("mmd is Coming")
            println(libs.findPlugin("androidApplication").get().get().pluginId)
            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("kotlinMultiplatform").get().get().pluginId)

            pluginManager.apply(libs.findPlugin("androidApplication").get().get().pluginId)

            extensions.getByType(ApplicationExtension::class.java)

            println("mmd done his job..")
        }
    }
}

build.gradle.kts file in app module:
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.composeCompiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id("com.sample.myproject.application-plugin")// --> this is my custom plugin
}

kotlin {
    android {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "21"
        }
    }

    jvm("desktop")

    sourceSets {
        val desktopMain by getting

        androidMain.dependencies {
            // android dependencies
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            // common dependencies
        }
        desktopMain.dependencies {
           // desktop dependencies
        }
    }
}

android {
    namespace = "com.sample.myproject"
    compileSdk = libs.versions.android.compileSdk.get().toInt()

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.sample.myproject"
    // other configurations
}

I've emptied my plugin and added configurations step by step and synced every time, as i add this:
extensions.getByType(ApplicationExtension::class.java)

It gives me the error.
I've initiated targets in my plugins like this:
extensions.getByType(KotlinMultiplatformExtension::class).apply {
     androidTarget()
     jvm("desktop")
}

But it didn't make any difference.

Try to update Gradle to the 8.0 version (in gradle.properties) and try to add this dependency to your dependencies block. It has helped to me.
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4") 


if it wouldnt help, let me know
